# Import format in kepler.gl from QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, csv, format

I try to export layer from QGIS to CSV, JSON or GeoJSON to add data in [kepler.gl](https://kepler.gl/demo).

I think I tried all options : geometrycollection or not, GeoJSON newline limited or not, comma, semicolon, CSV with WKT... Nothing compatible.
Any suggestions or specifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you can view any format, both CSV, JSON and GeoJSON directly from the kepler website or else from a notebook in jupyter lab or Google Colab.

In my case, once I have finished my work in QGIS, I export the file to GeoJSON format and assign it the CRS: 4326. Then kepler uploads it to the web page and I can play with the visualizations for my work presentations.